# Please help me identity this part (Duplo size)

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, duplo

I got a lot of pre-owned blocks and there's a part I couldn't figure what it is for. There is no part number printed on it; I guess it is not produced by LEGO, probably just some clone brands instead. It is Here are the pictures:

[image: pic1][image: pic2].

It is compatible with my other Duplo blocks and I'm curious what can I build with it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get it in a kit?

Comment: In other words, did you get it in a complete set that was never opened before you bought it? If so, you should look at the part list on the back of the manual to see what part it is (it won't tell what you can build with it). If you bought a random grouping of Lego Bricks, you should check out Bricklink and look for it there. Keep in mind you won't find third-party bricks in there, but I still recommend you look there anyway.

Comment: @mindstormsboi isn't that the whole point of this question asking YOU to go to Bricklink to find the piece since you are, probably, more knowledgeable?

Comment: I'm new to it, so I might not know where and how to find the part. But I guess I'll do it to save Since1996's time and hassle.

Comment: @Since1996 do you know the age of the block? Was it mixed with modern-day duplo blocks? That would give me some help finding it.

Comment: Wait, The older duplo blocks look quite identical to modern-day duplo blocks. Nevermind.

Comment: @mindstormsboi What I have are two huge containers of hand-me-down bricks,  some are Lego and some are knockoffs/clone-brands, all mixed together.

Comment: Oh, that could explain a few things. I didn't see the brick on bricklink, but I can't guarantee it's not a duplo brick.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for joining the discussion and trying to help. It turns out that the part to be identified is designed to be used as the handle for gears.

[image]

Comment: Was it a knock-off?

Comment: Gotta be a knockoff because there don't seem to be Duplo gears with 16 teeth (only 24 and 40) and the crank looks like this: https://brickset.com/parts/4493718/dacta-crank